# Isn't main(String args[]) a dynamic array?

Tags: java, arrays

I know that in `public static void main(String args[])` `args` is an array that will store command line arguments. But since command line arguments are passed during runtime, is the array `args[]` a dynamic array? In Java we know that an ArrayList is used to accomplish that kind of a job, so how does a simple array object store those arguments at runtime?

Comment: Define "dynamic array." In Java, array sizes don't have to be compile-time constants.

Comment: All arrays are "dynamic" in Java in the sense that their size isn't a part of their type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java arrays can have their size defined at runtime, not just compile time (unlike C stack allocated arrays).  However, the size of an array cannot be changed once it has been created.

It is perfectly valid to have an array created at runtime.  It is not possible to change the size after it has been created though:

```
    int argCount = 5;
    // ...
    String test[] = new String[argCount];
```

An `ArrayList` lets you grow and shrink the size of the underlying list at runtime.

Comment: ...frankly, C also has runtime sized arrays, they just don't expose their size in any way.

Comment: @Griwes C89 has not, unless you want to call the result of `malloc` an array.

Comment: @Griwes I was referring to stack allocated arrays in C, I've made that point a little clearer (hopefully)

Comment: @delnan, I mean specifically the result of `malloc` call allocating enough elements to form an array.

Answer (score 3):

*Every* array's size is determined at run time. The part that's not dynamic is that an array can't change its size *after* it is created, and that's also true of the array passed to `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Every array passed to every function is dynamic in the sense that the array is
dynamic from the callee's prospective. As for the special case of main; there 
is a mechanism called globbing that the shell (or command processor) of the 
operating system runs to then invoke the Main function (sometimes also called 
an Entry point). But this is a function of the Operating System (and the JVM) itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think, the args array has to be dynamic? The java virtual machine simply invokes the main method and passes the command line arguments as String array. There is no more 'magic' behind this!